# How to add Gender field to woocommerse Edit account

Tags: woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerse shop website and need to display the gender field within user profile page. I have tried to add the following code to functions.php

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );

function show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="gender">Gender</label></th>
            <td>
        }
    <select name="gender" id="gender" >
                    <option value="Male" <?php selected( 'Male', get_the_author_meta( 'gender', $user->ID ) ); ?>>Male</option>
                    <option value="Female" <?php selected( 'Female', get_the_author_meta( 'gender', $user->ID ) ); ?>>Female</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 <?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'gender', $_POST['gender'] );
 }
```

it is displaying the gender field within Wordpress user profile page but not within woocommerce user profile page.

Is that possible to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this after the email field in your custom `form-edit-account.php` (the one you copied from `woocommerce/templates/nyaccount`) file:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
        <option value="Male" <?php selected('Male', get_user_meta($user->ID, 'gender', true)); ?>>Male</option>
        <option value="Female" <?php selected('Female', get_user_meta($user->ID, 'gender', true)); ?>>Female</option>
    </select>
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
// ---- Save user input into database.
add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', 'custom_woocommerce_save_account_details');
function custom_woocommerce_save_account_details($user_id) {
    if ($user_id) {
        if (isset($_POST['gender'])) {
            if ($_POST['gender'] == 'Male' || $_POST['gender'] == 'Female') {
                update_user_meta($user_id, 'gender', $_POST['gender']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will definitely work.

Comment: If you're happy with that, can you please mark the answer as correct so others can find it as well? :-) –

Comment: Yes this is working perfectly. Thank you very much @Lutrov!

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce user profile pages are the same as standard Wordpress user profiles, so unless you're running other plugins which interfere in some way, the form elements you're trying to show will appear, irrespective of how the user was created.

By the way, it should be `<h2>Extra profile information</h2>`. Wordpress has changed the admin header structure quite some time ago. Also, `update_usermeta()` is deprecated. Use `update_user_meta()` instead.

Comment: Hey @Lutrov i had added that code within my functions.php. So i should see that Gender field in woocommerse edit account page right as i see it within admin panel edit account page but within woocommerse edit account page i don't see it. Could you help me to see why?

Comment: Do you mean when the user clicks the "edit your password and account details" link in the my account page? If so, you need to customise the standard Woocommerce `form-edit-account.php` file and add your extra gender field to that. Take a copy of `form-edit-account.php` in your Woocommerce `/templates/myaccount` folder and put it in your theme's `woocommerce/myaccount` folder. Then edit the custom version to include your gender field.

Comment: See this for an explanation about customising Woocommerce templates:
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: You should also look at the `woocommerce_edit_account_form` and `woocommerce_save_account_details` hooks. See this for more:

http://techiecorner.com/3337/how-to-add-user-custom-field-in-my-account-page-in-woocommerce/

Comment: Yes i tried by placing the wocommerce folder within my template file and i saw the new field added but i don't know how to save that field to DB?

Comment: From the link provided yes i see that it saves the data. One more question please. If i will have different new fields i need to add them within that same function or i need to create one for each @Lutrov?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107502/discussion-between-anahit-dev-and-lutrov).